# PIL resize/thumbnail cropping top bit of an image (portrait)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I am using PIL to resize images uploaded to the server. I have tried a simple algorithm to resize the image on the longest edge. But it is cropping a bit of the top portion in when the images are portraits. I think I made a mistake in the math formula. ANy help would be highly appreciated.

```
def scale_to_size(im1, local_image, size):
    width = int(config['image_sizes'][size]['width'])
    height = int(config['image_sizes'][size]['height'])

    wpercent = int((width/float(im1.size[0])))
    hsize = int((float(im1.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    im2 = im1.resize((wpercent, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    scaled_img = _rewrite_file_name(local_image, size) 
    im2.save(scaled_img)
    return scaled_img

def _rewrite_file_name(path, size):
    fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(path)
    return fileName + "_" + size + fileExt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 'medium'
    img = '/Users/.../tmp/photo.JPG'
    im1 = Image.open(img)
    scale_to_size(im1, img, size)
```

Widths:
small: 180
medium: 300
large: 600

I have tried using thumbnail but that didn't work out too well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing too many int->float float->int conversions. The result is that you lost some informations, also you are using `wpercent` instead of `width`. There is your code fixed:

```
def scale_to_size(im1, local_image, size):
    width = int(config['image_sizes'][size]['width'])

    wpercent = float(width)/im1.size[0]
    hsize = int(im1.size[1]*wpercent)
    im2 = im1.resize((width, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    scaled_img = _rewrite_file_name(local_image, size)
    im2.save(scaled_img)
    return scaled_img

def _rewrite_file_name(path, size):
    fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(path)
    return fileName + "_" + size + fileExt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 'medium'
    img = '/Users/.../tmp/photo.JPG'
    im1 = Image.open(img)
    scale_to_size(im1, img, size)
```